# get the frequency of the elements in a list java using Collections.frequency

Tags: java, list, frequency

I want get the frequency of the elements in a list java using Collections.frequency 
I must not use maps or sets or anything rather than the lists
I know about Collections.frequency but I can't implement it in my code to get the frequency of every unique word in a passage.
Also the number of of repeated words and most occurs word. 
Here What I have done So far.

```
import java.util.*;

// UniqueWords class
public class Lab {
    // main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> words;
        List<String> uniqueWords = new ArrayList<String>();
        String passage;
        int totalUniqueWords;

        // read passage from keyboard
        passage = scan.nextLine();
        // split the words from passage
        words = Arrays.asList(passage.split("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+"));

        // create iterator object and get unique words
        ListIterator<String> iterator = words.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String word = iterator.next();
            if (!uniqueWords.contains(word)) {
                uniqueWords.add(word);

            }

        }

        // sort the list
        Collections.sort(uniqueWords);

        // count of unique words
        totalUniqueWords = uniqueWords.size();

        // display the count
        // System.out.print(totalUniqueWords + ": ");
        // display the unique words
        iterator = uniqueWords.listIterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(iterator.next() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You will have to implement something like a `Map`. Yes it can be done without using `java.util.Map` but why?

Comment: It is actually a task I must do using just Lists

Comment: You can use two lists instead of a map : create a new list the size of your unique words list, iterate over unique words, check their frequency in the original list, store that result in the new list at the index your read the unique word from.